# Add reminder on google calendar with golang

Tags: go, google-calendar-api

I want to add a custom reminder to Google Calendar with golang:

```
event := &calendar.Event{
    Summary:     "Test GG calendar",
    Location:    "31 AAA",
    Description: "Test google calendar",
    Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{
        DateTime: "2016-12-27T17:30:00+07:00",
        TimeZone: "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh",
    },
    End: &calendar.EventDateTime{
        DateTime: "2016-12-27T17:40:00+07:00",
        TimeZone: "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh",
    },
    Reminders: &calendar.EventReminders{
        Overrides: []*calendar.EventReminder{
            {Method: "email", Minutes: 30},
            {Method: "popup", Minutes: 10},
        },
        UseDefault: false,
    },
}
```

When I run this code, google could not add event. I received this error: Unable to create event. googleapi: Error 400: Cannot specify both default reminders and overrides at the same time., cannotUseDefaultRemindersAndSpecifyOverride

Thanks

Comment: I found solution. We must add 
`ForceSendFields: []string{"UseDefault"}, `
after UseDefault: false, because they think false value is empty value and they didn't send it to server: https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3#EventReminders

Answer (score 2):

Based on my reading of [google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders), it seems that you should not specify the `UseDefault: false,` at the same time as setting the `Overrides`.  Do not put the `UseDefault: false,` part, and it will be defaulting to false as its only required to set when wanting to remove overrides that are in place already.

So the expected code is:

```
event := &calendar.Event{
    Summary:     "Test GG calendar",
    Location:    "31 AAA",
    Description: "Test google calendar",
    Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{
        DateTime: "2016-12-27T17:30:00+07:00",
        TimeZone: "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh",
    },
    End: &calendar.EventDateTime{
        DateTime: "2016-12-27T17:40:00+07:00",
        TimeZone: "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh",
    },
    Reminders: &calendar.EventReminders{
        Overrides: []*calendar.EventReminder{
            {Method: "email", Minutes: 30},
            {Method: "popup", Minutes: 10},
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In Go, default value of bool is false so UserDefault value always false when we didn't specify it. In this sample code, we must set false for UserDefault: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events. I don't know why google removed reminder sample code in Go part. You can see it in Java or PHP part.

Answer (score 1):

You should send `ForceSendFields` with `UseDefault` and set `UseDefault` to `false`

```
&calendar.EventReminders{
    Overrides: []*calendar.EventReminder{
        {
            Method:  "email",
            Minutes: 12,
        },
    },
    UseDefault:      false,
    ForceSendFields: []string{"UseDefault"},
}
```